# GraphQL context for user authentication with Express

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, prisma

I'm trying to create a simple user authentication process with GraphQL and Express, but each time I try to fire my query 'me' I got error.

This is my code :

The signup and login mutations are working perfectly.

But the me query is empty, like the user object is empty

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { AuthenticationError } = require('apollo-server-errors');
require('dotenv').config();

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const typeDefs = gql`
    type User {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        email: String!
    }

    type AuthPayload {
        token: String!
        user: User!
    }

    type Query {
        me: User
    }

    type Mutation {
        login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload
        signup(name: String!, email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        me: async (_, __, { prisma, user }) => {
            if (!user) {
                throw new AuthenticationError('You must be logged in');
            }

            try {
                const userData = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                    where: { id: user.id },
                });
                return userData;
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error('Unable to retrieve user data');
            }
        },
    },
    Mutation: {
        login: async (parent, { email, password }) => {
            const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });

            if (!user) {
                throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
            }

            const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

            if (!validPassword) {
                throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
            }

            const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

            return {
                token,
                user,
            };
        },
        signup: async (parent, { name, email, password }) => {
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

            const user = await prisma.user.create({
                data: {
                    name,
                    email,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                },
            });

            const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

            return {
                token,
                user,
            };
        },
    },
};

const context = ({ req }) => {
    const token = req.headers.authorization || '';
    try {
        const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        return { prisma, user };
    } catch (error) {
        return { prisma };
    }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context,
});

const app = express();

async function startApolloServer() {
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({ app });
}

startApolloServer();

app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
);
```

It's like nothing is saved after signup and the signin (mutations are working), and my 'me' query is empty.

Comment: Are you getting an authentication error or an undefined user?

Comment: My 'me' query trigger the 'You must be logged in' error because it's like nothing is saved

Comment: Are you sending the authorization token from the client? Is it valid? Does it have an `id` field? Your context function looks correct but it's worth logging what's going on in there.

Comment: I haven't client I triggered all of this from Apollo Studio

Comment: ok that's fine - what happens if you `console.log(token)` in `context.js`?

Comment: I have what I need my Bearer + token. But I think I know my problem, i'm so stupid... I don't sent the header Authorization with my Bearer + token in Apollo Studio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253374/discussion-between-michel-floyd-and-ellephant).

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution if you want to see the code

We changed a bit of code from the context, and the 'me' query.

> **AND DON'T FORGET TO CREATE A HEADER IN APOLLO STUDIO**
>
> You have to select Authorization and past the token

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { AuthenticationError } = require('apollo-server-errors');
require('dotenv').config();

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const typeDefs = gql`
    type User {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        email: String!
    }

    type AuthPayload {
        token: String!
        user: User!
    }

    type Query {
        me: User
    }

    type Mutation {
        login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload
        signup(name: String!, email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        me: async (parent, args, context) => {
            const user = context.user;

            if (!user) {
                throw new AuthenticationError('You must be logged in');
            }

            try {
                const userData = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                    where: { id: user.userId },
                });
                return userData;
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error('Unable to retrieve user data');
            }
        },
    },
    Mutation: {
        login: async (parent, { email, password }) => {
            const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });

            if (!user) {
                throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
            }

            const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

            if (!validPassword) {
                throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
            }

            const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

            return {
                token,
                user,
            };
        },
        signup: async (parent, { name, email, password }) => {
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

            const user = await prisma.user.create({
                data: {
                    name,
                    email,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                },
            });

            const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

            return {
                token,
                user,
            };
        },
    },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }) => {
        const token = req.headers.authorization || '';

        try {
            const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            return { user };
        } catch (error) {
            return { user: null };
        }
    },
});

const app = express();

async function startApolloServer() {
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({ app });
}

startApolloServer();

app.listen({ port: 8000 }, () =>
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:8000${server.graphqlPath}`)
);
```